# Using super in scala

Tags: java, scala, overriding

I have to convert a Java code to Scala and use overriding on type. My Java code is:

```
public class StatementNode extends Node {
public StatementNode()
{
    super(NodeType.statement);
}

protected StatementNode(NodeType type)
{
    super(type);
}
```

My equivalent scala code is:

```
class StatementNode extends Node(NodeType.statement) {
protected def this(`type`: NodeType) {
super(`type`)
}
```

Works fine for Java but I found that scala does not supports super keyword. So how are we going to apply overriding for type in scala? Please help!Let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 2):

In Scala overloaded constructors have to call the most generic form of the class constructor, which must also be the default one. That is, you can't have a parameter-less constructor for `StatementNode`, and then an overload that accepts a `NodeType` as a parameter without calling the parameter-less default constructor (which couldn't work, anyway).

Instead you can do something like this:

```
class StatementNode protected (`type`: NodeType) extends Node(`type`) {
    def this() = this(NodeType.statement)
}
```

You can make the default constructor `protected` and have the `NodeType` argument, and then provide an overload with no parameters that calls the main constructor and passes it `NodeType.statement`. This should effectively do the same thing.

There is no need to call `super` in Scala, because it is called through `extends Node(`type`)`, which is why the default constructor must contain the most generic form of the parameters.

Comment: What if you want to mimic this:
    public RuntimeException() {
        super();
    }

    public RuntimeException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public RuntimeException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public RuntimeException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
How do you do this in Scala without a lot of boilderplate?

Answer (score 0):

*Adding to Michael's answer:*

"Most generic" can also mean that **one set of arguments can be derived from another**. For example:

```
class Server(
  listenPort: ListenPort,
  authServerFactory: AuthServerFactory
) {

  def this(
    listenPort: ListenPort,
    auth0Domain: String,
    baseUri: URI
  ) = {
    this(listenPort, AuthServerFactory(auth0Domain, baseUri))
  }
  ...
  }
```

In this case `AuthServerFactory` can be created from two other arguments, but it might not be possible to do the other way around - deconstruct `AuthServerFactory` into several arguments.